# Descending Sort of repeated pattern of Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

```py
I have this data frame
import pandas as pd
ques=pd.DataFrame(data)
data={'sort_code': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3},  'text': {0: 'MCQ option3', 1: 'MCQ option 2', 2: 'MCQ option1 ', 3: 'MCQ option3', 4: 'MCQ option2', 5: 'MCQ option1'}}
ques=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**currently DF look like**

```
 sort_code          text
     1         MCQ option3
     2         MCQ option2
     3         MCQ option1 
     1         MCQ option3
     2         MCQ option2
     3         MCQ option1
```

**I want something like that**

```
sort_code          text
     3         MCQ option1
     2         MCQ option2
     1         MCQ option3 
     3         MCQ option1
     2         MCQ option2
     1         MCQ option3
```

**why I want this?**

I want to inverse the order of column `text`. Instead of MCQoption3 MCQoption2 , MCQoption1 options in inverse order should appear, like (MCQoption1,MCQoption2,MCQoption3). Actually the `Sort_code` associated with the text question (2 or 3 options against each question in real df) is in Ascending order like (123, 123). I want it in descending order to swap the position in "column `text`".

**What I have tried?**
I have tried to sort the `sort_code` but it results into sort value (1,1,2,2,3,3) that actually doesn't swap the multiple choices  within the set of three options.
In simple words I want to exchange the MCQ option3 with MCQ option1 for all the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WE can try `cumcount`

```
ques['key'] = ques.groupby('sort_code').cumcount()
ques = ques.sort_values(['key','sort_code'],ascending=[True,False]).drop('key',1)
ques
   sort_code          text
2          3  MCQ option1 
1          2  MCQ option 2
0          1   MCQ option3
5          3   MCQ option1
4          2   MCQ option2
3          1   MCQ option3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps:

1. add a column that designates what mc options correspond to a single question. You'll need this to properly sort the choices that correspond to a single question.
2. sort the dataframe by the question & the `sort_code` by ascending question and descending sort_code.

```
out = (
    ques
    .assign(mc_question=np.arange(len(ques)) // 3) # add a column chunks every 3 rows into a "question"
    .sort_values(["mc_question", "sort_code"], ascending=[True, False])
)

print(out)
   sort_code          text  mc_question
2          3   MCQ option1            0
1          2   MCQ option2            0
0          1   MCQ option3            0
5          3   MCQ option1            1
4          2   MCQ option2            1
3          1   MCQ option3            1
```

You can drop the `mc_question` column if you don't want it afterwards.